# Solidify Modifier solidifying the wrong way for only a few vertices

Tags: modifiers, vertices

I am  touching up a Jack O'Lantern that I made last year. I put the mouth back and manually de-solidified the thing. After I made my adjustments to the mouth and other minor things I wanted to make it a little more high poly so I added a SubSurf Mod to it. Then I naturally wanted it to be solid so I added the Solidify, but one of the carved out teeth is acting funny and solidifying the wrong way from all the rest of the mesh. I will give the file for you because this seems like a really hard problem to figure out just from pictures and an explanation.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/960ns0jtcsok1nv/Pumpkin%20StackExchange.blend?dl=0

Comment: I haven't looked at the .blend yet, but it sounds like a normals issue.  Did you try recalculating the normals [Ctrl]+[N].

Comment: That was the problem, I added an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your normals on the offending tooth had gotten flipped somehow.  I fixed this by selecting the entire mesh and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.  Alternatively you could have selected the individual faces and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > *flip normals*.

You can visualize normals in the 3D view under <kbd>N</kbd> menu > *mesh display* rollout > *normals*.

[image]